# Is it ok if the main CSS code is generated client-side?

Tags: javascript, css, performance, client-side

I have a build process that compiles LESS code into CSS, which will then be injected into a JavaScript string litteral, and concatenated with the main minified .js code. And that main code will then inject the CSS string onto the page.

One advantage to this is it will require just a single HTTP request to get the styles and scripts up and running.

However, are there any caveats to doing it this way?

**Edit**

A lot of people think that I am working on a brochure-type website. I'm, actually, working on a single page web app. So the app is entirely useless anyways if JavaScript is disabled. But at a usability standpoint maybe it's best if *some* styles were available to tell those with disabled JavaScript that JS is needed to get the app running.

**Edit 2**

I'm building a web app in Backbone.js. And also, I have multiple views. It's a terrible idea to load them all via script tags. And also, dependency management would be terrible. Hence, I'm using RequireJS to help me with all the dependency stuff.

But RequireJS also has this neat little plugin that lets you load plain text files that you can use in your app.

So from this, I was inspired to let each view have their own style, in their own LESS files.

Comment: Hmmm. Let me ask opposite question: what is the benefit of doing it this way?

Comment: Couldn't you just straight-away internalize the CSS without using Javascript? (`<style>` tags)

Answer (score 3):

1. Negligable, if any perf benefit.
2. If JS is disabled, no style
3. FOUC (Flash of unstyled content)
4. A rogue JS error could disable all styles.

Comment: True, but on the same note, users can disable CSS, too. Anyway, I hope that disabled Javascript becomes LESS and LESS common (no pun intended).

Comment: @Matt,at least think about javascript error that could stop css generating.

Comment: Rogue downvote 2 years later... wonder why?

Answer (score 2):

if you somehow get a js error before the css insertion code, your page might not get any styles at all.

Answer (score 2):

If you write CSS properly there will only be 1 HTTP request for it anyway for the visitors entire duration at your site.  Providing you ensure it is cached.  Your advantage isn't a very significant one, if any advantage at all.

JavaScript can not only be disabled by the user, but it can sometimes be blocked by a corporate firewall too, depending on heuristics over the type of instructions in there or where it is being served from.  E.g. *some* of your JavaScript files might run, whilst *some others* might not.  That happens very often to me at work.

Answer (score 1):

This is terrible for performance and shouldn't be used in production code.

Answer (score 1):

Since CSS can be overridden on the client side, I don't see any issue with generating it client-side.

Comment: I'm not sure I share this sentiment.  There have been many devices in the past that support CSS, but not JavaScript, especially with respect to mobile browsers (less so since the popularity of smartphones) and proxy browsers (where the page is rendered or reformatted on a server, like Opera Mini).  http://css-tricks.com/what-we-dont-know/

Comment: After reading your response as well as the other posts, I agree that this could prove suboptimal in certain scenarios. Thanks for the info. Since I usually develop for intranet where there are no mobile devices and all workstations are the same, I overlooked some of the less obvious criteria.

Answer (score 0):

FOUC (Flash of unstyled content).

Comment: Whilst this is very common in the wild, especially with novices using the likes of jQuery and AJAX based frameworks, but it is entirely avoidable.  That is, you do not have to wait for an event like onload or ondomready in order to append stylesheets to a document.